# Multivariate minimum with SymPy

Tags: python, sympy

I know how to symbolically find the minimun of a function with SymPy:

```py
from sympy import Symbol, sin, maximum
x = Symbol('x')

maximum(sin(x)*cos(x),x) # output 1/2
```

What if I want to do the same for a multivariate function ?
the following code does not work

```py
from sympy import Symbol, sin, maximum
x,y= Symbol("x","y")

maximum(sin(x)*cos(y),x,y)
```

I did not found a good way do to so in the SymPy docs. However SymPy is able do differentiate multivariate function so he might as well be able to find symbolically the minimum or at least some candidates (where the gradient is null)

Anyone as any tips on how to do it ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick version could be:

```
In [7]: f = sin(x)*cos(y)

In [8]: stationary_points = solve([f.diff(x), f.diff(y)], [x, y], dict=True)

In [9]: [f.subs(p) for p in stationary_points]
Out[9]: [0, 0, 1, -1, 0, 0, -1, 1]

In [10]: max(_)
Out[10]: 1
```

Comment: That's it ! Thank you very much